# How to enable a device to follow you?

Tags: tracking-devices

I am trying to find out what IoT devices I shall use to enable an device(say a small toy car) to have a ability to follow a particular person.

So far what I have found:

1. QR Code, print out the QR code and stick to yourself and let the car to track the QR code. Con: I don't expect my friends or family to print out an QR code and stick to themselves.... which looks funny, impractical
2. UWB.
   I noticed this technology recently. It enables cm-level positioning, but super expensive.

I am looking for an affordable solution.

Or use what I have:

1. Lidar
2. OpenCV AI Camera Oak 1 and Oak D
3. Raspberry Pi 4
4. An Android mobile Phone which has Wifi and Bluetooth
5. A GPS IoT Module

Not sure whether is it possible to use what I already have to enable the person following capability.

So my questions are:

1. How can I use affordable IoT devices(e.g. uwb) to enable tracking a particular person within short distance(e.g. short than 10 meters)
2. How to use existing devices which I have to do the person tacking?

---

Update

To make this question more specific, here is the details:

1. There will be more than one person
2. Among many person, the IoT devices + AI software should be able to just keep track that one particular person which specified at the beginning of launching an app
3. The AI software and app is not in the scope of discussion, this post is only discussing about the capable IoT devices
4. Terrain is not considered
5. Obstacles, since this is a discussion about closely following(within 1-1.5 meters), most of time there won't be obstacles, but admittedly, there might be times which an unpleasant in-between-cross happening, but it's expected to be very short period of time.
6. Size of the vehicle should not matter as I am seeking for a generic solution rather than a "hard coding" solution which can only work for a fixed size vehicle.
7. Speed is about walking speed which should not matter.
8. Batter life is not in the scope of this discussion, as long as the device is not consuming energy absurdly.
9. There are many devices out there, but not many have great documents, so prefer to have the devices which are well documented and affordable.
10. OpenCV is definitely a thing to incorporate, but as this is a "hardware" website, I'm too afraid to ask software related questions here, just to avoid my question to be closed because of this. But you are not restricted by this and are more than welcomed to discuss it and I will definitely like to talk about it :)

Comment: hi @jsotola I updated my post accordingly. Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: That’s still a very broad question… it probably depends a lot on a large number of constraints and requirements, like how is there only one person around, terrain, obstacles, size of the vehicle, speed, battery life requirements, and more. You should be able to use the camera and opencv to recognise the person and drive towards them, but they need to be in the field of view of the camera, obstacles would add more difficulty, and so on. Regarding UWB I believe there are quite cheap solutions available as well.

Comment: thanks @jsotola I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: hi @jsotola , make sense. I have changed my "is it possible xxx" questions to "how" questions.